# Django NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.slug

Tags: django, database, django-admin, profile

I'm trying to create user profile automatically and it didn't work so I tried adding it with the admin panel and it gives me this error

> IntegrityError at /admin/users/profile/add/
>
> > NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.slug

Heres my user profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='profile_pics')
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

here the view that create the profile:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been Updated!')
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Automatic profile generating signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Where is the `slug` field of your `Profile` model? Did you forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after (possibly) _removing_ that field?

Comment: yes it did help to create a profile using administrator but the signal is still not working, Anyways Thanks it worked

Comment: Do you have your signals in a separate `signals.py` file?

Comment: yes, I have signals in separate file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the main problem was about `makemigration` and `migrate`. The other problem that you're facing (**signals are not taking place**) could be solved by simply *loading* signals.

Just add this code to the `apps.py`, inside your app directory:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class <your_app_name>Config(AppConfig):
    name = '<your_app_name>'

    def ready(self):                      # <---- add this
        import <your_app_name>.signals    # <---- add this
```

Comment: Now it gives this error **The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it** after user signs up on register page but the user profile is generated